# Error with Oracle trigger, invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have the following DML statement that is working perfectly, i have tried to make it into a trigger but it isn't working.

**DML statement**

```
UPDATE HOLIDAY_RESERVATION R SET SUBTOTAL = 
   NVL((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = R.IN_FLIGHT_ID), 0) * NVL(R.IN_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO,0) +
   NVL((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = R.OUT_FLIGHT_ID), 0)* NVL(R.OUT_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO,0) +
   NVL((SELECT AC.ACC_PRICEPN FROM ACCOMMODATION AC WHERE AC.ACC_ID = R.ACC_ID), 0);
```

**Trigger statement**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HR_SUBTOTAL
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON HOLIDAY_RESERVATION
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SELECT 
      NVL((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = :NEW.IN_FLIGHT_ID), 0) * NVL(R.IN_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO,0) +
      NVL((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = :NEW.OUT_FLIGHT_ID), 0) * NVL(R.OUT_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO,0) +
      NVL((SELECT AC.ACC_PRICEPN FROM ACCOMMODATION AC WHERE AC.ACC_ID = :NEW.ACC_ID), 0)
      INTO :NEW.SUBTOTAL
   FROM DUAL;
END;


Errors for TRIGGER HR_SUBTOTAL:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
2/4      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
4/92     PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "R"."OUT_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO": invalid identifier
```

The error has to be in the * multiplying bit, because if i get rid of multiplying bit, it works maybe it has to be enclosed in parenthesis or something with another select.

Comment: Well i got rid of both R's , but is still giving the same error

Comment: `PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "OUT_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO": invalid identifier`

Comment: change `R.` to `:NEW.` in trigger code. Then it will be equivalent to the update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no alias set for R in the query.

You should use the :NEW or :OLD option in the select statement as following

```
SELECT 
  NVL((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = :NEW.IN_FLIGHT_ID), 0) * NVL(:OLD.IN_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO,0) +
  NVL((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = :NEW.OUT_FLIGHT_ID), 0) * NVL(:OLD.OUT_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO,0) +
  NVL((SELECT AC.ACC_PRICEPN FROM ACCOMMODATION AC WHERE AC.ACC_ID = :NEW.ACC_ID), 0)
  INTO :NEW.SUBTOTAL
FROM DUAL;
```